# Showing error fix plugin version and sync projects in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

i am new in `Android Studio`and when i create a new project suddenly i just got an error message i.e, `Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "9ba5989c7b283b0ec145cc20641f7155619d6148"`

Here is my `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "************"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

My build.gradle(project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

i have updated my Android studio 2.0 but it always showing `Fix plugin version and sync project` when open create a project.please anyone can tell me what i should do to rectify this problem.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Click on that message to fix it. Let it upgrade required plugins.

Answer (score 0):

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'` instead of this use

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.+'` this fixed the same error for me!